# Escaping curly brace for Awk commands over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

I tried the following command and got an error:

```
$  ssh -q rmthost "bash -c 'cat /var/tmp/5|awk '''{print \$1}''' >/var/tmp/redirect 2>&1'"
Missing }
```

(Note: the "bash -c ' is needed since the login shell for the account on rmthost is csh)

disabling brace expansion doesn't work:

```
$ set +B
```

I also tried:

```
$  ssh -q rmthost "bash -c 'cat /var/tmp/5|awk ''''{'print \$1'}''''>/var/tmp/redirect 2>&1'"
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
```

intermediate script files will do but I prefer one-liners since I have 10+ such similar commands need to be run at different point in time.

Is there a way to escape the braces in such case?

thanks.

Comment: single quotes prevent variable expansion. Most likely you don't need any escaping at all

Comment: there is a single quote for bash -c string already so the single quotes in awk command need to be escaped also. that's the tricky part.

Answer (score 3):

I played with this a little while...  And I think what you really want to do is "simplify."  My local shell is bash, and my remote is tcsh... here is what I came up with as functional (in accordance with your filenames).

```
ssh -q rmthost "awk '{ print \$1 }' /var/tmp/5"
```

Shell escaping is tricky enough that you really have to think about "why" you want to do something like this (in deference, say, to leveraging an intermediate script file).

Maybe even better is to use cut?

```
ssh -q rmthost 'cut -f1 /var/tmp/5'
```

If shell encapsulation and redirection is absolutely required...  (Note the escape on ampersand.)

```
ssh -q rmthost "sh -c \"awk '{ print $1 }' /var/tmp/5\" \&> /var/tmp/redirect"
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I need that bash -c staff coz the remote login shell is csh while the real command I want to run on rmthost includes bash-style output redirection such as 2>&1. it can be done easier by an intermediate script file. but I prefer command lines since I have quite a lot of such different commands to run on a remote server at different point in time...

Comment: I added a clause in my answer to this... The key for me was just building from the simplified version. The last trick was escaping the ampersand - likely this is a csh thing.  As my setup is very close to yours, it's likely that my script will work (and is a direct answer to your question), but I encourage you also to look at jil's answer, as his/hers enables you to write a multi-line script much more conveniently.  The real answer likely lies somewhere in between.

Answer (score 0):

Try with heredoc syntax (also, useless use of cat eliminated):

```
 ssh -q rmthost <<'EOI'
 bash -c "awk '{print $1}' < /var/tmp/5 > /var/tmp/redirect 2>&1"
 EOI
```